# Stop Spring JPA Implementation for few Interface

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data

I want to implement few jpa repository for dynamo DB but at the same time i want to use few default spring data implementation (for mysql DB):-

class DynamoImpl implements SomeJPARepository {}

interface SomeJPARepository extends JPARepository{}

But i am getting error in log **"found 2 implementation of SomeJPARepository"** ,first DynamoImpl second
SomeJPARepository(Provided by spring data proxy) ?

How to stop JPA proxy impementation ?

I don't want to use @Qualifier due to high number of occurrence of this class in project .

Comment: If you want to implement a custom implementation, did you look at https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations and follow the necessary steps there?

Answer (score 0):

Name them accordingly and use `@Qualifier`

Comment: I dont want to use qualifier as i woluld be replacing thousands of files .